# Menu strip c# from csv file

Tags: c#, menu, strip

Is there any way to load a csv file to populate a menu strip in c# i have a csv file with 5 columns the first one is the group so would like it in the first menu then everything under it needs to be in a sub menu is this possible

Comment: What are you using? Winforms? Wpf? If you split it in two tasks, first creating menu items from code and parsing a CSV. If you combine those you have your program.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.csv");

var menuStrip = new MenuStrip();

// This:
//
// foreach (var line in lines)
// {
//     if (line.Trim() == string.Empty) { continue; }
//     var lineSplit = line.Split(',');
//

// Is the same as:
//
foreach (var lineSplit in lines.Where(l => l.Trim() != string.Empty).Select(line => line.Split(',')))
{
//
    var subMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem(lineSplit[0]);
    menuStrip.Items.Add(subMenu);

    for (var i = 1; i < lineSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        subMenu.DropDownItems.Add(lineSplit[i]);
    }
}

 this.Controls.Add(menuStrip);
```

Comment: Thanks for that i am getting an error stating "where can not be found in th sytem array"

Comment: You'll need to add 'using System.Linq;' for that. That thing is called Extension Method. Google it, and also google system.linq extension methods - which are all very cool and useful.

Comment: @KevinBabb I've edited the answer so you can see how to avoid using the Where method. It has the exact same functionality, either way.

Comment: Ok its kinda working i have a menu with all the correct headers but no drop down sub menus

Comment: Can anyone help i cant figure out why the sub menu item dont show

Comment: Strange indeed. I don't get them as menus either. Probably something stupid that I'm missing. If no one has the answer by tomorrow, I'll have more time to go over it and find whats up.

Comment: @KevinBabb Such a silly mistake. I updated the code. The problem was that I did "menuStrip.Items.Add(lineSplit[0]);" instead of "menuStrip.Items.Add(subMenu);" so the subMenu item wasn't really added to the menu, and therefore had no children in the menu itself.

Comment: Sure thing. Accepting the answer would be appreciated, and also helpful for others with the same question :)